# Список со списками. Последовательный вывод каждого n-ого значения из каждого m-ого списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список со списками:

```
   grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
           ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
           ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
           ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
           ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
           ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
           ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
           ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
           ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

Требуется вывести сначала первые символы каждого списка, потом вторые символы каждого списка и т.д.
Чтобы получилось сердечко:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В подсказке к заданию сказано что требуется использовать 2 цикла.
У меня пока получилось вывести только первый символ каждого из списков списка grid:

```
def paint():
    x=0
    y=0
    for i in grid:
        print(grid[x][y],end='')
        x=x+1
```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы программа, после перебора всех элементов списка grid и вывода каждого 1ого значения каждого списка, начинала проход по всем элементам списка grid заново и выводила уже 2ой элемента каждого списка и т.д.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `print(*map("".join, zip(*grid)), sep="\n")` :)

Answer (score 1):

Так? Два цикла есть.

```
#Поможем человеку
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

Index = 0

for x in range(len(grid[0])):
    string = ''
    for arr in grid:
        string += arr[Index]
        
    print(string)

    Index += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

как вариант:

```
def paint():
    for c in range(len(grid[0])):
        for r in range(len(grid)-1, -1, -1):
            print(grid[r][c],end='') 
        print()         
        
paint()
```

Answer (score 1):

Будет работать только если вложенные списки имеют одинаковую длину.

```
for i in range(len(grid[0])):
    for j in range(len(grid)):
        print(grid[j][i], end='')
    print()
```